# Include my former PhD advisor in publication or submit by myself?

Tags: publications, authorship, biology

I have been doing basic molecular biology research since 2001 and am now doing other things that I love, but I still work with molecular biology. I was working with my protein of interest during my PhD work. I left the program in 2013, basically because my advisor lost a lot of funding.

I have just finished writing a nice extensive review on my protein, with diagrams that I made, and I submitted it to a high impact journal (IF: 14.35). In short, I got an email back from the journal telling me that they "unsubmitted" it and asked me to do a few things and resubmit. To me, them emailing me back two days after I initially submitted it asking me to revise and resubmit is actually a good sign.

Should I just submit it as me, unaffiliated with any company, institution, or university, or should I now, email my former PhD advisor and tell him that we could get a review published in a really good journal based on the protein I was studying?

Comment: "To me, them emailing me back two days after I initially submitted it asking me to revise and resubmit is actually a good sign." Well, if this was after an initial quality check by journal staff I wouldn't read anything into it. Those checks tend to be very superficial, and don't look at the scientific value. If an editor actually looked at the paper, it probably only means that the paper is in-scope for the journal.

Comment: @Anyon Yes. And OP is doubtless aware that having the adviser's institution on the paper's authors may lubricate publication matters a bit too.

Comment: "without knowing the impact factor of around 14.35" what does the IF have to do with anything?

Answer (score 12):

The usual rules of co-authorship apply: If someone contributed intellectually in a significant way to the development of what you report in the paper, then they should be a co-author. If they didn't, then they shouldn't.

Comment: Normally, I'd second this. But from the OP's sentence: *I was working with my POI during my PhD work where I left the program in 2013 basically because my advisor lost a lot of funding.* it's possible the he/she didn't complete the doctoral program and had to leave the university. As such, OP would be naturally aggrieved at their former department and would likely feel, that on the matter of **getting the work to publication**, their adviser had no serious input - albeit that the adviser started them on the project. We need to know more on the collapse of the project and the adviser's efforts.

Comment: @Trunk Well yes. My answer does not give a recommendation about what to do because I don't know anything about the adviser's involvement.

Comment: @Trunk indeed I was about to thank Wolfgang for his very straight forward answer, although you have probably raised a serious question that will resolve this. So, he had a lot to do with my POI and my work during 2011 to 2013. In fact, I proposed to write the review back in late 2012 when I was in the prog and under him. However, everything on the review, I wrote. Thus, I should probably reconsider having him on the paper, because yes, it was his idea for me to work on this protein??

Comment: @Trunk As shitty as it would be, it doesn't matter. They contributed to the work pre-publication. Not be involved in "getting the work to publication" does not disqualify them from authorship.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Thus, I am going to contact him Monday and tell him about the review, that would probably be the right thing to do and the next logical step anyways.  The thing is, is that I am not currently associated with any university, institution, and I have started my own businesses.  He is probably going to be very happy that I wrote it and I think it will take.  So, when I submit it again, the only thing I know to do to associated my name with something is to put down the company that I have founded??

Comment: @John If he should be on the paper, you really should not have submitted it without him. He may not take it well. Your other question is unrelated, and you should look up other questions on this site about it.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- yes, you are right. I know him and he most likely will take it in stride and after a few minutes, will be fine. I wrote and designed the whole thing, his contribution dates back to 2011 when he was my advisor in the program and I told him that I was going to write a review, and he said ok. And if course, he helped my with the actual development of this project throughout my time with him. I will email him Monday and see what he says. But thanks for your help.